# Why Java application can't execute procedures if I added grant all privileges?

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, mybatis

I have a Java web application that uses MySQL. In the webapp log it shows the following message:

```
Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: User does not have access to metadata required to determine stored procedure parameter types. If rights can not be granted, configure connection with "noAccessToProcedureBodies=true" 
to have driver generate parameters that represent INOUT strings irregardless of actual parameter types.
```

Checking in this forum I saw a solution where I had to add `GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc TO webapp@'%';` in order to solve the problem. The thing is I see this solution as intrusive because I giving access to every procedures from databases to webapp user.
Why shouldn't be enough adding grant all privileges on `bdwebapp.*` to `webapp@'%'`; in order to enable stored procedure executions from web application?

I see the problem appears when web application invokes the procedure. Even though, if I execute by mysql shell: `call sp_getClientByCode(1);` It gives the result without `GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc TO webapp@'%'`.

This the Java instruction using mybatis when calling stored procedure.

```java
@Select("{call sp_getClientByCode(#{clientId, mode=IN, jdbcType=INTEGER})}")
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
List<App> getClientByCode(@Param("clientId") Integer userId);
```

This is the procedure implementation:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`webapp`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_getClientByCode`(clientId INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT id, name FROM clients where id = clientId;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

The java connector is trying to validate the type of the arguments to your stored procedure independently of the mybatis declaration.

You could apply `noAccessToProcedureBodies=true` like the error message suggests.

A better solution however is to use [MariaDB Connector/J](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-connectorj/) that uses a [MariaDB unprivileged operation](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-j/commit/4bc6130221c8d160c499272ef9c9241992093b7c) (using [information_schema.parameters](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-parameters-table/)) to examine the arguments of stored procedures.

Comment: If I add the instruction IN before the parameter name. I mean sp_getClientByCode(IN clientId INT). Is also necessary to apply noAccessToProcedureBodies=true?

Comment: You've got the test environment :wink:. I strongly suspect the error message is independent of the mybatis annotations. So yes, pulling a MariaDB Connector/J to avoid using `noAccessToProcedureBodies=true` is probably still needed. FYI based on this I raised the [mybatis issue to autodiscover parameter direction and type](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/2685).